# Migrating Microstrategy reports from on prem with Teradata as backend to Microstrategy Cloud with snowflake as backend

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata, microstrategy

We have the Microstrategy reports pointing to Teradata as backend. The plan is to migrate the Microstrategy from On Prem to Microstrategy Cloud with Snowflake as backend.

I wanted to know the steps and various ways/processes to do this migration.

Comment: Are you asking about how to migrate from MicroStrategy On-prem to MicroStrategy Cloud, or from Teradata to Snowflake, or both? If both, I would recommend splitting these into 2 separate questions as you are more likely to get a productive answer to each question that way

Comment: yes its both. The on prem has the backend as Teradata, whereas on Microstrategy cloud, the backend is snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

For the data, there are two basic approaches:

1. Export the data to files on a cloud storage platform and then use Snowflake’s COPY INTO command to load the files into Snowflake
2. Use a tool that can read from Teradata and write to Snowflake. This could be a dedicated ETL tool or a generic coding tool like Python

Answer (score 0):

For Metadata backup, you can use "mstr bak" to do the migration. This is officially supported to migration from on-prem to cloud. Refer to https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/Current/Cloud/en-us/Content/upgrade_mstr_back_up.htm

For warehouse migration(Teradata->Snowflake), I believe there are other tools that support this.